# Setting up Apache and Subversion to use LDAP (Windows Active Directory) group authentication

Tags: svn, active-directory, apache2, ldap, apache

I am attempting to setup Apache httpd with LDAP access for Subversion, and need a bit of help:

What I want to do is use a group for access. If you are a member of the group, you have read/write access. If you are not, you have no access.

The group record in our LDAP server (*ldap://ldap.MyCompany.com/DC=MyCompany,DC=COM*)

```
CN=SVN-GROUP,CN=Users,DC=MyCompany,DC=com
```

and the members of the group are in this record like this:

```
member: CN=David Weintraub,OU=Users,OU=Brooklyn,OU=Accounts,DC=MyCompany,DC=COM
member: CN=Joe Public,OU=Users,OU=Cincinnati,OU=Accounts,DC=MyCompany,DC=COM
```

If you look up my record in LDAP, you'll see:

```
memberOf: CN=SVN-GROUP,CN=Users,DC=MyCompany,DC=com
Name: David Weintraub
Distinguished Name: CN=David Weintraub,OU=Users,OU=Brooklyn,OU=Accounts,DC=MyCompany,DC=COM
sAMAccountName: dweintraub
```

What I'd like to do is to login as `dweintraub` (which is my Windows account) with my Windows password. I also don't want to specify the Windows Domain as part of my login. Everyone will be part of the `mycompany` domain.

I'm trying to go through the Apache httpd website, but it's a bit hard to put everything together.

Which reminds me, can anyone recommend a good Apache book?

Comment: Have you checked the alias definition for the access file in Subversion? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz (look for [aliases])

Comment: That would mean I have to modify my Subversion configuration every time a new employee comes or goes. I want to pass this task off onto our Windows administrator who has to set this up anyway. Whenever we get a new employee, and that employee is a member of this group, they have Subversion access. When that employee leaves, they no longer have Subversion access.

Comment: jbruni, could you please post an example of an ldap-group DN?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using Apache 2.2, this is actually pretty easy. Make sure you configure Apache to have both mod_ldap and mod_authnz_ldap enabled.

Here is the minimum needed for AD ldap authentication and authorization:

```
<Location /path/to/repo/>
    AuthType basic
    AuthName "My Repository"
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.example.com:3268/dc=example,dc=com?sAMAccountName" NONE
    AuthLDAPBindDN "DN of service account allowed to search"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "Password of service account allowed to search"
    Require ldap-group DN of group allowed access to repo
</Location>
```

For the ldap-group, don't surround the DN with quotation marks. By specifying port 3268, you will be connecting to the global catalog. I found this works much better because Apache won't get a bunch of referrals.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I haven't had time to try it out yet, but I can see what I was doing wrong. I didn't have that ?sAMAccountName on the end of my AuthLDAPURL. Are there any good books on Apache httpd?

Comment: I'd start with the O'Reilly books. They're always good. Unfortunately, it looks like Definitive Guide (3rd edition) is based on apache 2.0. It should be enough to get you started.

Comment: everything works form me except for require-group part, I am also using mod_dav_svn and file as provider, svn access file allows me to make some directories readonly for some users, I want to make sure that my entire repo is available to only one AD group, cant get that part to work