# Managing commit rights in svn by delegating to project managers

Tags: apache, svn, hook, commit, rights

We have multiple projects in svn repo.And for each project there are many users.As number of users is large so its troublesome to manage their commit rights using "Auth file".
I have read somewhere that we can delegate user's rights to their managers by creating a text file.But i am not sure how to achieve this and perhaps hOOKS need to be configured for this .As i am new to SVN so need your expert advice.Please guide me how to achieve this and if you have hook already confgiured p,kindly provide.

[How to setup access control in SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81361/how-to-setup-access-control-in-svn)
I have seen this link and answer by VonC is great and perfect for me.But i dont know how to start .. can anybody help me out here as i am not pro in svn and unix .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Preface**

1. Using single repository for multiple projects is Bad Idea (tm): one repo - one project
2. Forget immediately about old as mammoth's shit SVN 1.5 - use at least 1.6 on client and server (1.8 may be best choice)

**Face**

Simplified user-management for SVN-users can be reached using [LDAP-based authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5653169/960558) instead of ordinary file (in case of "repository per project" `<location>` from answer will be location of **each** repo with SVNPath, in case of old structure `<location>` must be linked to every root of project) and having different groups for different repositories in `Require ldap-group` directive - read also Apache 2.2 docs in [Apache Module mod_authnz_ldap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authnz_ldap.html) part. From management POV, LDAP-auth and permissions means: each developer must be in LDAP-tree, included in one or more related to repositories groups

In case of additional requirement for [Path-Based Authorization](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html) within repositories and using groups inside authz-file, you may find useful [LDAP Groups to Subversion Authz Groups Bridge](http://thoughtspark.org/2009/01/20/using-ldap-groups-with-subversion-s-authz-file/), which allow you to regenerate authz-groups from LDAP-data

As result, most (if not all) SVN-related ACLs can be managed in LDAP-side only

Comment: We have multiple releases in project and for each release we have made branches/trunk/tags .So for a single repo (Java Code) we have many projects.But for other changes we have diff repo for eg for Sql changes we have diff repo.

Comment: @JazzR - can't grok your workflow (or terms? Is "release" really "product"?) Anyway, ACLs *inside repo* isn't question of auth-technology, it's Path-Based Authorization. And see my remark 1

Comment: yeah ... i used project specific term.Apologies.One thing i need to clarify,we are using different repositories.But within one repository ,we have different folders(projects)which are divided into branch,tag,trunk.Honestly Lazy ,am looking for other options,like maintaining a text file by managers and svn admin will handle rights of managers only.