# LDAP Integration with two different system

Tags: java, ldap, ldap-query

Our Java based web application uses LDAP authorization and authentication mechanism .
And same for our version control system (SVN) which is using LDAP authentication.

In new requirement we've to integrate SVN with Web Application - like execute some basic SVN command through web application.

As I dont want use hard coded userID passowrd to connect SVN.
Can anyone suggest me a good way to connect SVN through Web Application as both system using LDAP ?
[image]

Comment: Duplicate of [Setting up Apache and SubVersion to use LDAP Windows Active Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5652982/setting-up-apache-and-subversion-to-use-ldap-windows-active-directory-group-au)

Comment: Not a duplicate, I have added more details.

Comment: @EJP What makes you think that he uses Active Directory?

Comment: @Michael-O We're using Active directory