# How to use Subclipse in Eclipse Helios (Android)

Tags: java, android, svn

I am a Android Developer and I want to establish the Subverson

Now I have configure my eclipse with the plugin Subclipse properly and SVN is also properly configured by checking in perspective .Now I am not getting any idea how to use it ,how to create svn server, the local repository to svn and how can I share a project in LAN so  my team can work on same project.I have surf lot on net but I am not getting any proper way ....

Comment: By the way, Helios is over a year old. You might want to try Indigo.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion requires that there be a central repository/server on which to store all your data. So, you should decide whether you want to host this in-house, or whether you wish to outsource the repository hosting:

**In-house Repository**

An SVN server does not require a lot of resources, thus does not require the fastest hardware available, just make sure you have a reasonable amount of disk space available - depending on the types of items you are storing (multimedia files, Jars, images, etc).
Without going into the details on installing and configuring the server, just head to Apache to [download](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html) a suitable binary, and follow their installation instructions. While you can get away with creating just a single user in the server, I would recommend creating one for each team member as this makes it easier to see who last checked-in a file.

**Outsourced Repository**

There are several organisations that are able to host your project(s), and the choices are determined by whether your project is open or closed source.

Open source projects have several FREE options, such as [Google Code](http://code.google.com/projecthosting/) or the old favourite [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/).

For Commercial closed-source projects, if you have the budget you could opt for a paid service, such as [JIRA Studio](http://www.atlassian.com/hosted/studio/) from Atlassian, who offer SVN hosting, plus their suite of tools - however this is not free. There are probably many other such commercial offerings, however I've not used them personally, so cannot comment on them.

**Using Subversion**

With most of the setup information out of the way, you'll need to know how to use subversion itself.

Basically, once you have linked your project to SVN, your day-to-day use of SVN will probably consist of the following steps:

1. Edit Source code
2. Update from HEAD (to incorporate other changes)
3. Resolve any conflicts that occurred from other users updating the same line of source code as yourself
4. Commit your changes to the repository
5. Repeat

When it comes to releasing your software product, it is common to use the Tagging functionality of SVN, which tags the current revision of each item in your repo with a given name (such as "MyProduct-1.0.0"), allowing you to continue development on the HEAD branch, but still recreate this version at any point in the future.

You will probably find [this ebook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) to be of particular help when it comes to using SVN.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Subversion uses a client-server model unlike tools like Git that consist of clients. It appears that you are trying to use subversion without a server. I would recommend installing subversion and then following a tutorial such as [this one](http://www.tonyspencer.com/2007/03/02/setup-a-subversion-server-in-4-minutes/) to set up a repository for your team to use.

Comment: thanks for your quick replay and  I want to establish the server bt the thing is that I am new to this and I dont know how to move forward after downloading subecplise ....

Comment: I am now going to follow you link and try then let you know I am getting or not

Comment: Hey i am doing my work on windows and i think the link u give me is on linux

Comment: I believe that you can do it about the same way on windows, however Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880302/which-windows-svn-server-should-i-use